# MCV Core Dropdownlist Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core

I have a model that looks as follows:

```
 public partial class RoutePartner
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid PartnerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RouteCompany { get; set; }
}
```

The partnerId comes from another TABLE that has an Id and Name. I'm trying to build my CRUD forms to load the list of partners and make them available to the form. That is the best way to do this in MVC Core? I see many .NET examples but none for CORE.

One last point is that partner drop down should be populated by a stored procedure.

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class doesn't have to be the same as your database. Why not have a class called Partner that has the ParnterID and PartnerName? In your RoutePartner class have a Partner property, instead of just the ID.

```
Public class SomeViewModel //Used by your view
{
  public RouteParnter {get; set;}
  public ParnterList List<SelectListItem> {get; set;}

public static List<SelectListItem> PopulateDropdown()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
        DataTable someTable = Database.LoadParnters(); // Database is your data layer
        foreach (var row in someTable.Rows)
        {
            ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = row["PartnerName"].ToString();, Value = row["PartnerID"].ToString(); });
        }
        return ls;
    }
}

 public partial class RoutePartner
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Partner SomePartner { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RouteCompany { get; set; }



  public RouteParnter(Guid id)
     {
    DataRow returnedRow = Database.LoadRouteParnter(id);
     Id = id;
   // Assuming your DataRow returned has all the info you need.
     RouteCompany = row["RouteCompany"];
     SomePartner = new Partner();
     SomePartner.PartnerId = row["PartnerID"]; // cast to guid, just example
     SomePartner.PartnerName = row["PartnerName"].ToString(); 

     }
    }

     public class Partner
    {
        public Guid PartnerId { get; set; }
        public string PartnerName { get; set; }

    }
```

I would loosely couple the data layer. You could use ADO.NET or any other way to communicate with the database. I usually do this by creating a parameterized constructor (say taking in an ID to load), to call the data layer. The data layer returns a DataTable, DataRow, DataSet, or a custom object. In the constructor, you populate the values of the RouteParnter object. Likewise you could have a List in the ViewModel.

Comment: Good idea, better than what I was thinking. How would I populate the Model RoutePartner? Also I still am not sure how to show the Partner as a drop down.

Comment: updated a bit. I did not include the data layer, or how you would use the dropdown. Essentially return the data from the Data Layer, Load it in the Entity Layer, and have a separate ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I don't understand the Database.LoadRoutePartner(id) method. Is that something that I write because Database.LoadRoutePartner() does not exist in Database class.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide a quick update to how I solved this issue. I ended up creating a PartnerContext for EF. Once created, in controllers that need access to the list, I placed PartnerContext.ToList() into ViewBag and then used ASP helpers to load the list.